# Nonparametric ICC

Tags: nonparametric, intraclass-correlation

Anyone can suggest me a nonparametric version of the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC)? My model have the following details: two-way random effects model, consistency, average ratings as unit. I am using irr R-cran package.

thank you

Comment: The ICC is not, in itself, a parametric statistic. You can conceive of the ICC regardless of the distribution of the data. What exactly do you mean by "nonparametric ICC"?

Comment: I have seen that in some studies the ratings are firstly examined to check a possible violations from normality, and then ICC is computed. Is it mandatory? What if the ratings are far from normality?